# What caused the EXIF data to be changed in these files I expect to be identical?

Tags: metadata, exiftool, windows-7

I have two folders full of images, folders ***1a*** and ***1b***, that I took, and in the process of sorting them for backing up, I noticed they are not the same. The dates in Windows Explorer are all wrong, and although I can swear I did no modifications to either of them (folders, and the images inside) I cannot be certain.

At first I thought only the dates have been changed somehow, but while comparing them with diff application, some of the images are *binary same* and some differ somehow.

Taking Exiftool and comparing EXIF data from two images that differ, here is the results;

```
3c3
< [System]        Directory                       : 1a
---
> [System]        Directory                       : 1b
5,7c5,7
< [System]        File Modification Date/Time     : 2014:06:07 09:58:43+02:00
< [System]        File Access Date/Time           : 2015:08:24 02:11:23+02:00
< [System]        File Creation Date/Time         : 2014:06:06 22:00:30+02:00
---
> [System]        File Modification Date/Time     : 2014:06:06 22:00:32+02:00
> [System]        File Access Date/Time           : 2015:08:24 02:11:47+02:00
> [System]        File Creation Date/Time         : 2014:06:07 09:56:28+02:00
19,22d18
< [JFIF]          JFIF Version                    : 1.01
< [JFIF]          Resolution Unit                 : None
< [JFIF]          X Resolution                    : 1
< [JFIF]          Y Resolution                    : 1
26d21
< [IFD0]          Orientation                     : Rotate 90 CW
32a28,38
> [IFD0]          Sensitivity Type                : Standard Output Sensitivity
> [IFD0]          Custom Rendered                 : Normal
> [IFD0]          Exposure Mode                   : Auto
> [IFD0]          White Balance                   : Auto
> [IFD0]          Digital Zoom Ratio              : 0
> [IFD0]          Focal Length In 35mm Format     : 27 mm
> [IFD0]          Scene Capture Type              : Standard
> [IFD0]          Gain Control                    : High gain up
> [IFD0]          Contrast                        : Normal
> [IFD0]          Saturation                      : Normal
> [IFD0]          Sharpness                       : Normal
37d42
< [ExifIFD]       Sensitivity Type                : Standard Output Sensitivity
52,53c57,58
< [ExifIFD]       Exif Image Width                : 4608
< [ExifIFD]       Exif Image Height               : 3456
---
> [ExifIFD]       Exif Image Width                : 3456
> [ExifIFD]       Exif Image Height               : 4608
56,65d60
< [ExifIFD]       Custom Rendered                 : Normal
< [ExifIFD]       Exposure Mode                   : Auto
< [ExifIFD]       White Balance                   : Auto
< [ExifIFD]       Digital Zoom Ratio              : 0
< [ExifIFD]       Focal Length In 35mm Format     : 27 mm
< [ExifIFD]       Scene Capture Type              : Standard
< [ExifIFD]       Gain Control                    : High gain up
< [ExifIFD]       Contrast                        : Normal
< [ExifIFD]       Saturation                      : Normal
< [ExifIFD]       Sharpness                       : Normal
74c69
< [Olympus]       Preview Image Start             : 2927433
---
> [Olympus]       Preview Image Start             : 2927265
107,108d101
< [InteropIFD]    Interoperability Index          : R98 - DCF basic file (sRGB)
< [InteropIFD]    Interoperability Version        : 0100
114,115c107,108
< [IFD1]          Thumbnail Offset                : 9234
< [IFD1]          Thumbnail Length                : 6301
---
> [IFD1]          Thumbnail Offset                : 7946
> [IFD1]          Thumbnail Length                : 6251
122c115
< [Composite]     Thumbnail Image                 : (Binary data 6301 bytes, use -b option to extract)
---
> [Composite]     Thumbnail Image                 : (Binary data 6251 bytes, use -b option to extract)
```

**Is there anything inside this results (note: these are only the diff results) that can tell what has been changed / done to them?**

My usual toolbox includes: ACDSee 32 2.4 (the very old one, the classic), Windows Explorer and Photo Viewer.

Answer (score 3):

The image has been rotated.  Image in directory 1a is 4608 px wide, 3456 px high and has an Orientation tag of Rotate 90 CW.  So it is a portrait picture that is in landscape orientation.  If you look at it with a image viewer that has been told to ignore orientation, it will look like it is turned on it's side.  The image in 1b is 3456 px wide and 4608 px high, so it has been rotated.

I would assume that the images in dir 1a would be the originals, since when a camera saves the image, it is in landscape mode and it sets the Orientation tag based on the orientation of the camera, but I would double check to be sure.

It looks like the rest of the data has just been reorganized.  Items like Thumbnail Offset and Preview Image Start have been properly changed to reflect the reorganization of the exif data.  Thumbnail Length has changed, which seems to me that the Thumbnail has also been rotated or possibly rewritten, though I could be wrong on that.  The rest of the Exif data has changed position within the Exif as well, but still fine.

Both ACDSee and Windows Photo Viewer appear to be able to losslessly rotate jpg images, though ACDSee appears to need have a 'force lossless rotation' option set.

Comment: This seems very likely. From the question, some images are binary identical and some are unchanged — I bet only the portrait-orientation photos are changed.

Comment: Interesting, but if 1a files are not rotated, why is Windows Explorer (in thumbnails mode) showing them rotated?

Comment: Some quick research online suggests that Windows explorer and Windows Photo Viewer do not honor the orientation tag, but that appears to have changed at some point.  My quick test using Windows 8.1, both explorer (using large thumbs) and the Photo Viewer properly orient images based upon the orientation tag.

Might I ask what version of Windows you are using?  This is the type of stuff I like to keep track of.

Comment: @StarGeek - Windows 7.

Comment: @StarGeek - What I meant, is that using ACDSee and Photo Viewer, both orient images when displaying portrait wise. So that confused me, since I expected at least 1a or 1b images to be different.

Comment: Both programs are reading the Exif Orientation tag and rotating the image to the proper orientation for display.  You can try this.  Make a copy of the file in 1a.  Then use this ExifTool command: `ExifTool -orientation= FILE` replacing FILE with the full path to the copy.  Then load the copy into either program.  It should now be on its side.

Comment: @StarGeek - So what you're saying is, regardless of the orientation tag in either image, the program will orient it (rotating if necessary) to display it properly (portrait wise). It's just that in the case of the 1a it has to do it, while the other 1b is already oriented. I may have mixed them up in the explanation, but that being the general idea?

Comment: I apologize if I'm explaining it poorly. What I'm trying to say is the opposite of that. The image in dir 1a is horizontal, but it's meant to be viewed vertically, so it looks like [this](http://imgur.com/1pmHnqs).  It has a orientation flag that says it needs to be rotated ClockWise 90 degrees.  Because it has the orientation tag, ACDSee and Photo Viewer know it needs to be rotated and does it automatically and show you [this](http://imgur.com/s3ivEIT). The image in dir 1b does not have an orientation flag, so both those programs display it without rotation. (cont)

Comment: It has already been rotated so already looks like the second image.  If you remove the orientation tag from the image in 1a, your programs will display it looking like the first image.  The orientation tag is what tells ACDSee and Photo viewer to rotate the image.  Without it, they won't rotate the image.

Comment: @StarGeek - Your explanation is very good, it seems I misunderstood the first time. Could you check if I got it right this time? 1a image is landscape with an "90 CW" orientation tag which has been set by camera upon shooting. Whether the orientation tag is going to be inside depends on the orientation of the camera upon shooting? 1b image was manipulated (pixels were reorganized) so now it is portrait without the orientation tag. Was the orientation tag lost when the image was rotated? My misunderstanding was partly caused by

Comment: the fact that I thought that when you rotate the picture, you merely set a different orientation tag, not manipulate the pixels altogether?

Upon showing in a viewer, 1a is landscape mode but with an orientation tag so the viewer shows it portrait like, and the image 1b is portrait without the orientation tag so it also comes out portrait like. Have I got it right this time?

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  But yes, you have it right now.  There are basically 3 ways to rotate an jpg image.  The easiest is to change the Exif:Orientation tag.  But that requires the software to be able to recognize the tag.  Facebook, for example, used to ignore the tag (not sure if it still does).  The second way is to use lossless rotation.  Not all software can do this and it requires that the width/height of the jpg be divisible by 8 or 16, depending upon the encoding.  Both ACDSee and Windows Photo Viewer can do this.  The third way is to load the jpg and rotate, then resave.(cont)

Comment: This way is destructive and not recommended if it can be avoided.  See [Compression artifact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compression_artifact) for more info.  Luckily, if the image came from a camera, it almost certainly can be rotated losslessly.  I have yet to come across a camera image that couldn't.